# connect WinCE device without ActiveSync

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce

I try to connect WinCE device without ActiveSync as written here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28VS.90%29.aspx

Connection has been succeeded from Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

1) Is there possible disconnect device and connect another device?

2) Is there possible to use connection without ActiveSync with other utilities (for example from C:\Program Files\CE Remote Tools\5.01\bin)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connectivity that article is talking about is CoreCon.  You can programmatically access it, so you can determine what platforms are available, connect, disconnect, etc.  the VSD team blogged about it [with the first in the 5-part series here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/archive/2007/11/20/corecon-api-part-1.aspx) and the rest of them available at the top of [this list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/).